# How can i parse the 10 user id's in the mysql query so that i can know how much money was deposited by these 10 user in the upcoming months

Tags: python, mysql

> 1. First Step

I have a MySQL query

```
select UserId 
from Users 
where Depositor between 'June' and 'July'
```

This query gives me 10 unique users id's,
Now I have store this unique user id's in a variable name `'result'`

> 2. Second Step

Now I have another query

```
select sum(RealCash) 
from bank 
where  Status=1 and TransactionType=4 where date between june and july
```

This query gives me the total sum of money deposited by all the users in the bank

**Question** :
**I want to parse the 10 user id's in the above step 2 query so that I can know how much money was deposited by this 10 user in the upcoming months**

Is there any solution for this?
I'm using python and MYSQL

Comment: can't you just select sum of money instead of userID

Comment: The second query has 2 where clauses, so it will give you an error

Comment: the query is not the issue i will change the second where condition, i need to parse user id's in the query that's the main question..Thankyou

Comment: Please provide more details as described in [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952).

Comment: Add GROUP BY into 2nd query. Without it all rows are treated as one group.

Comment: *`where Depositor between 'June' and 'July'`* - will give empty output, because `'June' > 'July'` (string compare).